# Jquery Tabs not displaying properly after upgrading to 1.8.9

Tags: jquery, tabs

Hey all, I'm having a strange issue today after upgrading to the latest jqueryui. My tab containers aren't working anymore. Its styling the tabs, but appearing like so:

[image: Jquery Tabs Issue]

As well, all three content frames are being shown in a large column, instead of one at a time. Has anybody seen this problem before? It works fine if I go back to 1.8.5, but I need to use the newer version now. Help!?

I'm not styling these tabs in any way outside of jquery, and the markup is exactly like the examples. Removing the content from the tabs has the same result, all three frames show up in a column.

*edit *

It does appear that jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js is causing the problem, not the theme. The tabs stop working when I update to 1.8.9. I take it from the lack of responses so far that this isn't a common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that if you [update your theme](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) the problem will go away. If not, then I will adopt a puppy. But since I already have eight of the little beasties, I will do nothing.

Comment: Looks like you'll be making a trip to the spca, I'm using 1.8.9 themes.

Comment: Damn it. Not again! Hmmm, I will think on this some more.

Comment: I honestly don't know what to suggest. If I was in your position, I would probably 1) Work out if the theme or jQuery UI is causing the problem. 2) Use a text comparison app (such as Beyond Compare) to see exactly what has changed. These types of problems are generally headachy, I hope someone else here as a better suggestion.

Comment: Get this - redownloaded 1.8.9 and overwrote the file, same size in KB, tabs are working. I forgot to save the original to compare, but maybe this indicates a bug with how JqueryUI packages the .zip?

Comment: @Gallen - Maybe; interesting stuff and scary at the same time.